# Getting first group name in PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis

With the following code, I did not succeed to get the first group name of the tree.

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
import os
#coding=system


def group_name():
  root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
  print root.name()


group_name()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to get the name of the groups, try this:

```
for group in iface.legendInterface().groups():
    print group
```

And the firt group name only:

```
groups = iface.legendInterface().groups()
groups[0]
```